# Consider the stability of a equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

> For
> $$
> \dot{x}=x+f(x,y),\quad \dot{y}=-y+g(x,y)
> $$
> where $f,g\in$ Lip $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$ and
> $$
> |f(x,y)|\leq c(x^2+y^2),\quad |g(x,y)|\leq c(x^2+y^2)
> $$
> in a neighborhood of the origin, consider the stability of $(0,0)$.

After I tried several special $f,g$, I believe the origin is Lyapunov stable, but I do not know how to prove the general case. I tried to constuct some Lyapunov function but failed. I have no idea how to use the Lipschitz condition.

Could you give me some hint to find a Lyapunov function? Or you can suggest your own way. Appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm sorry for my previous comments, I was mixing this task with a rotational $\dot x=y+f(x,y)$, $\dot y=-x+g$. There is no way to perturb away the saddle point of the actual system.

Comment: Could you document some of the "several special $f,g$" that lead you to proclaim the stability of the origin, and explain that on one example? Under the given assumption, trajectories close to the origin and even closer to the $x$ axis should move away from the origin.

Comment: I calculate again and found the previous mistake. Now I want to try a simpler problem with only one variable: $\dot{x}=x+f(x)$,...,$f(x)\leq c|x|^2$,....And I believe your claim is correct but how do you prove it?

Comment: What about $f(x,y) = 0$?

Comment: In that case you can get an exact solution. Assume $x(0)>0$, the other case goes similar. $$x-cx^2\le\dot x\le x+cx^2\\c-u\ge\dot u\ge-(c+u),~~u=x^{-1}\\c+(u(0)-c)e^{-t}\ge u(t)\ge -c+(u(0)+c)e^{-t}\\ \frac{x(0)e^t}{1+cx(0)(e^t-1)}\le x(t)\le\frac{x(0)e^t}{1-cx(0)(e^t-1)}$$ This means that close to $t=0$ and for $x(0)<c^{-1}$ the solution follows the characteristics of the exponential for the linear part. This remains valid longer the closer $x(0)$ is to zero.